# Why isn't there a telecommute option when searching from careers front page?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

In the careers search, there is a checkbox to restrict the search to telecommute only. On the front page of careers.stackexchange.com, however, there is no such checkbox. While I realize that I can just put "Telecommute" in the location search, it took me some time to figure that out.

There are ways around this problem, and it does have a negative UI effect (it may make things cluttered), but it would make the site self-consistent.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

If you'd like something else, a nice red pencil freehand mock up would be nice.

Comment: Not really sure if there is a better solution, but I had the constant thought "I wish I could search telecommute without having to go to the main search page first" until I saw that.

Comment: @Nick. See my answer for a possible minor tweak...

Answer (score 1):

Would this be (slightly) better?

[image: sample screenshot with Telecommute in square brackets]